# Google TCP loadbalancer port forwarding

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using tcp load balancer in google cloud platform, How do i forward the the frontend configurations

```
<static-ip>:8000 and <static-ip>:80
```

to the 8000 port of a backend instance group ?

The temporary solution i have used is by logging into each machines in the instance group and used ip-tables to forward the incomming traffic in port 80 to port 8000. But this is not a feasible solution if the number of instances are more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port forwarding cannot be implemented in google cloud's tcp loadbalancer, but available in HTTP and HTTPS load balancers. The port forwarding should be done through ip-tables in the machines.